# How to make constraints work in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way for constraints to actually work in Snowflake?

A primary key is created. Still duplicates can be inserted in the table. Giving options like cascade update and delete cascade are not working with Foreign key

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5):

if you read the Snowflake documentation you will see that only NOT NULL constraints are enforced, all other constraint types are informational only.

I am guessing that the reason for this is that Snowflake is an analytical, rather than an OLTP, database and therefore the expectation is that constraints are enforced in your ELT processes (as is normal practice) rather than in the DB.

Comment: In that case, what about the implementation of cascade update and delete?

Comment: Again, you perform this explicitly in your ELT routines

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake does not enforce constraints except not null.
[Snowflake Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html) . I think we cannot enforce a constraint in snowflake database but you can apply the constraint in your ETL tool(if using)